# How to only allow digits, letters, and certain characters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to make a password checker but how do I make it so I can write an error if there are characters other than digits, upper/lowercase and (,),$,%,_/.

What I have so far:

```
import sys
import re
import string
import random

password = input("Enter Password: ")
length = len(password)
if length < 8:
    print("\nPasswords must be between 8-24 characters\n\n")
elif length > 24:
    print ("\nPasswords must be between 8-24 characters\n\n")

elif not re.match('[a-z]',password):
        print ('error')
```

Comment: https://regexone.com/

Comment: Are you asking how to write a regex that matches the conditions you set?

Comment: This is a very helpful tool:  https://regex101.com/

Comment: You should learn the basics of regexes first. Open up your favourite search engine and search for something like "regex tutorial".

Comment: In addition to the above, you should use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch) rather than `re.match` to match the whole string rather than just the beginning.

Comment: Here's a link that might be related to your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117733/validation-a-password-python

Comment: Why not just make one regex for this and call it a day? Save yourself time, code, save your users time, sanity... `[a-zA-Z0-9()$%_]{8,24}`. There's nothing more annoying than a system prompting you multiple times for an incorrectly formatted password. Just present the user with all the conditions you want. `Password must meet the following requirements:\n- Length must be between 8 and 24 characters\n-Valid characters are ASCII letters (a-z or A-Z), ASCII numbers (0-9) or the following characters ()$%_`. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`elif not re.match('^[a-zA-Z0-9()$%_/.]*$',password):`

I can't tell if you want to allow commas. If so use `^[a-zA-Z0-9()$%_/.,]*$`

Answer (score 3):

You need to have a regular expression against which you will validate like this:

```
m = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9()$%_/.]*$')
if(m.match(input_string)):
     # Do something...
else:
     # Reject with your logic ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using RegEx, you can try this self-explanatory solution

```
allowed_characters=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','(',')','$','%','_','/']

password=input("enter password: ")
if any(x not in allowed_characters for x in password):
  print("error: invalid character")
else:
  print("no error")
```

Comment: Very nice when you have few allowed characters and don't want to use RegEx. Thanks.

Comment: I would just replace `allowed_characters` with the built-in module `import string` where you can use `allowed_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + r'()$%_/.]*$'` to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you should be raising exceptions when something goes wrong:

```
if re.search(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9()$%_]', password):
    raise Exception('Valid passwords include ...(whatever)')
```

This searches for any character in the password that is not (^) in the set of characters defined between the square brackets.