# how to check a list element?

Tags: python, loops, exception

I need help to solve a code to check for valid password and condition are:

1. The password should be of at least eight characters.
2. It is a combination of alphabets, numeric digits `0` to `9`, and special characters `'_'`, `'@'`, `'#'`, and `'*'`. No other character is allowed.
3. It should contain one capital alphabet, one special character from (`'_'`, `'@'`, `'#'`, `'*'`), and one numeric digit from `0` to `9`.

```
temp_list=['_','@', '#','*']

flag=False

for a in range (6):
    try:
        pas=list(input("enter password :"))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if len(pas)<8:
        print("try again")
        continue
    elif len(pas)>8:
            for j in range(10):
                for t in temp_list:
                    if str(j) in pas and t in pas:
                        flag=True
                        continue
                    else:
                        flag=False
                        break
    if a<5:
        if str(j) not in pas or t not in pas:
            print("J: ",j," T: ", t)
            print("try again")
            continue
    else:
        break
if flag==True:
    print("Valid password")
```

in this code it does not print valid when the password entered is valid.

Comment: This is pretty messy. I see no check for upper case. In the first loop you seem to have mixed up `break` and `continue`. See if you can [edit] this into a [mre].

Comment: We have a cubic light year of password validation questions here; did you look at some old ones?

Comment: E.g., here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553464/password-validation-in-python

Comment: I'd suggest you extract a [mcve] as well. Also, consider unit testing your function, so that changes to fix one case don't break earlier working cases. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be replacing the `elif` part with:

```
[...]
    elif:
        for j in range(10):
            for t in temp_list:
                if str(j) in pas and t in pas:
                    flag = True
        if flag == False: # no special characters/numbers found
            print("try again")
            continue
        else:
            break
[...]
```

so that you check your flag **after** you loop through the possibilities of special characters and numbers.

But this code is still missing the check for capital letters, as mentioned in the comments. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697535/how-can-i-check-if-a-letter-in-a-string-is-capitalized-using-python) to see how to do this in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `RegExr`  version of validation check this hope it help you:

```py
        import re

        temp_list = ['_', '@', '#', '*']


        def check_password(psw):
            """ make sure psw respect rules

            1. It is a combination of alphabets, numeric digits 0 to 9,
            and special characters '_', '@', '#', and '*'. No other character is allowed.

            2.It should contain one capital alphabet, one special character
            from ('_', '@', '#', '*'), and one numeric digit from 0 to 9.
            """
            if not re.match(r'^([0-9]|[a-zA-Z]|_|@|#|\*)+$', psw):
                return False, """It is a combination of alphabets, numeric digits 0 to 9, and special characters '_', '@', '#', and '*'. No other character is allowed"""
            if not re.match(r'.*?[A-Z].*', psw):
                return False, 'Password should contains at least one capital alphabet'
            if not re.match(r'.*?[_|@|#|\*].*', psw):
                return False, 'Password should contains at least one special character from (%s)' % ','.join(temp_list)
            return True, 'Valid password'


        valid = False
        for a in range (6):
            try:
                pas = input("enter password :")
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if len(pas) < 8:
                print("Password should contains at least 8 letters try again.")
            valid, msg = check_password(pas)
            if not valid:
                print(msg, 'try again.')
            else:
                valid = True
                break  # pass word is valid
        else:
            print('You all ready tried 6 times sorry!')
            not_valid = True

        if valid:
            # do you work here
```