# Check string without regex

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I dont want to use regex. I have a string of password. I want to check condition like , it should contain alphabet, numberic , capital letter, small letter, special characters. How to achieve this without regex?
What would be the fastest way to do this?
I have made list of a-z and A-Z and 0-9 and special characters. But that is consuming time to write all things in list. 
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you best, please read and create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117733/validation-of-a-password-python could help you on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` to check if any of the characters in the password are in one of the character sets you describe. Then wrap that in `all` to ensure one of each of your requirements are satisfied.

```
import string

def validate_password(password):
    char_sets = {string.ascii_lowercase,
                 string.ascii_uppercase,
                 string.digits,
                 string.punctuation}
    return all(any(letter in char_set for letter in password) for char_set in char_sets)
```

For example

```
>>> validate_password('password')
False
>>> validate_password('Password1!')
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set of tests like these:

```
pw = 'Ab1!'
has_alpha = any([x.isalpha() for x in pw])
has_num = any([x.isdigit() for x in pw])
has_upper = any([x.isupper() for x in pw])
has_lower = any([x.islower() for x in pw])
has_symbol = any([not x.isalnum() for x in pw])

is_proper_pw = has_alpha and has_num and has_upper and has_lower and has_symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps by comparing the ASCII values of the characters in the password? Something like:

```
pw = "Hello"

# convert password to ASCII numbers
pw_to_ascii = [int(ord(c)) for c in pw]

# ASCII range for capital letters
cap_range = range(65,90)

# CHeck for capitals
for c in cap_range:
    if c in pw_to_ascii:
        print("Contains capital.") # replace with your desired action
```

You could do additional checks for special characters by just checking different ranges. Its a naive approach but does the job. If you want to limit the possible characters, as most passwords do (such as spaces), you could just add a range to check for those specifically.