# how would i create a program in python to implement this?

Tags: python-3.x

A   password    must    have    at  least   eight   characters.
• A password    consists    of  only    letters and digits.
• A password    must    contain at  least   two digits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validation of a Password - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41117733/validation-of-a-password-python)

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to this code as your answer :

```
import re

def validate():
  while True:
    password = input("Enter a password: ")
    if len(password) < 8:
        print("Make sure your password is at lest 8 letters")
    elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
        print("Make sure your password has a number in it")
    elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None: 
        print("Make sure your password has a capital letter in it")
    else:
        print("Your password seems fine")
        break

   

validate()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate such passwords use this code:

```
import string
import random

letters =string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits
comb = letters + digits

length = random.randint(6,98)

password = random.choices(digits,k = 2)
password+= random.choices(comb, k =length)
random.shuffle(password)
password = ''.join(password)

print(password)
```

I assumed the max length of a password is 100. you may want to change it.