# How do I check if a letter is not in a word?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while True:
    profilePassword = input("Password: ")
    if profilePassword == "":
        print("Your password can't be blank!")
        continue
    else:
        pass
    for n in profilePassword:
        if n == " ":
            print("Your password can't contain spaces!")
            break
        elif n not in "1234567890":
            print("Your password has to contain at least one number!")
            break
        elif n not in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
            print("Your password has to contain at least one lowercase letter!")
            break
        elif n not in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            print("Your password has to contain at least one uppercase letter!")
            break
        else:
            continue
```

So I am trying to create a program that checks if your password is correct. For some reason "not in" doesn't behave very well. If I write, for example, asd123, it will say that the password has to contain at least one number, which it has.
Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: I would take a step back and talk yourself through the logic flow you're attempting. The first thing you should notice is that your logic flow is never going to get past `elif n not in "1234567890"` unless the first character in `profilePassword` is a number. You'll run into similar issues for the rest of the `elif` statements.

Comment: You have it backwards. Your code asserts that __every__ character is not a space, but is a number __and__ a word character. You should be checking if there _is_ a character that's a number/word character, not if there's a character that _isn't_.

Comment: Oh, yes! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments said too, you are checking every `char` for being a number (if it is, the second `elif` fails, because you check if it's a character). This is not what you want to do, you just want to make sure the whole string contains a number.

You may use [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) for this:

```
if re.search(regex, password):
    # regex found something
else:
    # no match
```

Personally I think it's better to tell the user all the things that failed (not juts the first fail).

```
import re

def setPassword(profilePassword):
    msg = ""
    if re.search(r' ', profilePassword):
        msg += "* Your password can't contain spaces!\n"

    if not re.search(r'\d', profilePassword):
        msg += "* Your password has to contain at least one number!\n"

    if not re.search(r'[a-z]', profilePassword):
        msg += "* Your password has to contain at least one lowercase letter!\n"

    if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', profilePassword):
        msg += "* Your password has to contain at least one uppercase letter!\n"

    if msg == "":
        print("Setting password was successfull")
    else:
        print("Setting password was not successfull due to following reasons:")
        print(msg)



setPassword("")
setPassword(" ")
setPassword("a")
setPassword("A")
setPassword("1")

setPassword("asd123")

setPassword("aA1")

while True:
    profilePassword = input("Password: ")
    if profilePassword == "":
        print("Your password can't be blank!")
        continue
    else:
        pass
    setPassword(profilePassword)
```

Also found this while searching: [Checking the strength of a password (how to check conditions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709638/checking-the-strength-of-a-password-how-to-check-conditions)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do loops. Convert your password to set and check intersections, along the following lines:

```
digits = set("0123456789")
pw = set("password")
if not digits.intersection(pw):
     # no digits in password
```