# How to register a @staticmethod password checker callback for a ttk.Entry widget? Switching frame scenario

Tags: python, tkinter

I recently wrote a script to perform [dynamic password strength check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49281416/how-to-register-a-staticmethod-password-checker-callback-for-a-ttk-entry-widget/49283771#49283771) and @martineau showed that I could us `functools.partial` to supply a `tk.StringVar` argument to my static method `_passwordStrength()`. However, when I apply this solution to the solution by @BryanOakley on  [switching between multiple frames/pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/5722359), somehow my dynamic strength check code fails. My Test script and the error msg that I get are given below. I don't understand why my script is telling python that 'Login' has  attribute '_LoginPage__passwordStrength'. It should be searching for static method `__passwordStrength` in class `Login` and not class `LoginPage`. Somehow, I am not able to `register` the `@staticmethod`.

Appreciate guidance on fixing this AttributeError.

**Test Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# python3 modules
import re
import functools


# tkinter modules
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class Login(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **options):
        """
        """
        # Initialise App Frame
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.__createPages()

        self.parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def __createPages(self):
        """Create Login and NewUser pages."""
        self._pages = {}
        for F in (LoginPage, NewUserPage):
        #for F in (LoginPage, ):
            page_name = F.__name__
            page = F(parent=self)
            self._pages[page_name] = page
            page.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.showPage("LoginPage")

        self.parent.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.parent.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def showPage(self, page_name):
        '''Show the desired page. '''
        #1. Bring to foreground the desired page.
        page = self._pages[page_name]
        page.tkraise()

        #2. Always want window to resize to fit new page.
        top = page.winfo_toplevel()
        top.geometry('')

    @staticmethod
    def __passwordStrength(svar, P):
        '''Check password strength.

        A password is considered strong if:
            8 characters length or more
            1 digit or more
            1 symbol or more
            1 uppercase letter or more
            1 lowercase letter or more'''

        password = P
        print (password, len(password))

        # check length
        if password == '':
            svar.set('')
            return True

        # check length
        if len(password) < 8:
            svar.set('Password is too short')
            return True

        # check for digits
        if not re.search(r"\d", password):
            svar.set('Password missing a number.')
            return True

        # check for uppercase
        if not re.search(r"[A-Z]", password):
            svar.set('Password missing upper case letter.')
            return True

        # check for lowercase
        if not re.search(r"[a-z]", password):
            svar.set('Password missing lower case letter.')
            return True

        # check for symbols
        if not re.search(r"\W", password):
            svar.set('Password missing a symbol.')
            return True

        # Passed all checks.
        svar.set('Strong password provided.')
        return True


class LoginPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.pwstrength = tk.StringVar()

        pwLabel = ttk.Label(self, text='Password:')
        valcommand = self.register(
            functools.partial(Login.__passwordStrength, self.pwstrength)
            )
        vcmd = (valcommand, '%P')
        pwEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15, show='*', validate="key",
                            validatecommand=vcmd)
        #pwEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15, show='*')  #This works
        pwWarn  = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.pwstrength)

        switchpage = ttk.Button(self, text='Create New User?',
                                command=lambda:parent.showPage("NewUserPage"))

        pwLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nse', padx=10)
        pwEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=10)
        pwWarn.grid( row=2, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=10)
        switchpage.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, ipady=10)


class NewUserPage(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pwstrength = tk.StringVar()

        pwLabel = ttk.Label(self, text='Password:')
        pwEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width=15, show='*')
        pwWarn  = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.pwstrength)

        switchpage = ttk.Button(self, text='Login?',
                                command=lambda:parent.showPage("LoginPage"))

        pwLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nse', padx=10)
        pwEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=10)
        pwWarn.grid( row=2, column=1, sticky='nsw', padx=10)
        switchpage.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew', columnspan=2, ipady=10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('400x350+300+300')

    login = Login(root)
    login.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.mainloop()
```

**Error Msg:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/login_v4.py", line 152, in <module>
    login = Login(root)
  File "~/login_v4.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.__createPages()
  File "~/login_v4.py", line 35, in __createPages
    page = F(parent=self)
  File "~/login_v4.py", line 113, in __init__
    functools.partial(Login.__passwordStrength, self.pwstrength)
AttributeError: type object 'Login' has no attribute '_LoginPage__passwordStrength'
```

Comment: Don't use method name starting with `__`. They will be name mangled.

Comment: You changed the name of the static method in my linked answer from `_passwordStrength` to `__passwordStrength` which causes name-mangling to occur. See link in @KlausD's comment.