# flask password complexity checker

Tags: python, flask, passwords

I need to check for password complexity on a flask user registration form. I thought about using the password_strength python library but didn't have much success with it. I only need to check to make sure the password matches the following criteria:

Min of 12 char
at least 1 UC
at least 1 LC
at least 1 Num
at least 1 Sym

Here is my Login Registration code within Flask:

```py
@auth.route('/signup', methods=['POST'])
def signup_post():

    email = request.form.get('email')
    name = request.form.get('name')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    # if re.match(r"^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[@#$])[\w\d@#$]{6,12}$", password):

    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()  # check to see if user already exists

    if user:  # if a user is found, we want to redirect back to signup page so user can try again
        flash('email address already exists')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.signup'))

    new_user = User(email=email, name=name, password=generate_password_hash(password, method='sha256'))

    # add the new user to the database
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
```

As you can see, I was thinking of using a regex to perform this task but I'm not sure how to inform the user the password doesn't meet the complexity requirements and re-prompt for a more secure password. Thanks

Comment: You could check the different criteria with regex and then grant the password a security score based on each result and return a message accordingly. If it's too weak, you can return a message with the expected security measures required and render it on your website.

Comment: Is there really no decent library to help with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way would be a regular expression search function that returns the errors in the complexity of the password. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709638/checking-the-strength-of-a-password-how-to-check-conditions#32542964).

Comment: I ended up using javascript in my html to perform this task on the client side instead of having to deal with Python code to do this. I still had to use some regex on the javascript side to make it works. Thanks